# How can I fetch imap reply message only through PHP?

Tags: php, imap

How can I fetch iMap reply message only through PHP? Also extract the signature part from that mail.

I used two methods, listed below

```
$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1));              
$message1 = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2));
```

This script gives all content of the particular mail, posted message and and its replies etc. I need to fetch recent reply of the particular message, not all conversations under the messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting only a certain part of an email body using imap\_body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597535/getting-only-a-certain-part-of-an-email-body-using-imap-body)

Comment: Typo? `1.2` vs. `1, 2`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get a reply message, simply because. It'a a classic email and all add-ons are done on client side.
Also, getting only the signature can't be done because it's added on the email body so it's not possible to distinguish

Comment: But I need it very much, Any alternate?